# No source available for main in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I googled a lot and also on stackoverflow I came across similar topics, but none of them solved by problem.

I created a new Eclipse Hello World project. It is compiled by

```
g++ -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
```

Everything runs fine, but if I start debugging it I get the

```
No source available for "main() at 0x4008cc"
```

error.

All topics I came across indicated the -g and -O0 flags should be there. 
As you can see I have them, but still the same problem.

Comment: Looks like you do have a `int main();` declaration in your file, but no matching implementation. But a complete source example which reproduces the problem would be really helpful!

Comment: What OS and what version of Eclipse/CDT are you using?

Comment: Your compilation command isn't complete, linker step misses. So you don't have any executable file, only an object one

Comment: instead of `-g` try `-g3`